# React & Zustand & Immer Asynchronous update state

Tags: reactjs, state-management, zustand, immer.js

I'm using React with `zustand` and the `immer` middleware of `zustand`.

I use a custom class in the zustand store, and with immer I can update the state and the custom class instance in the state with mutable patterns. At most of times, everything works well.

However, I have an `async` function in the custom class, which will make changes on the instance info, However zustand `set()` method doesn't allow async function, how can I call the `async` method in my custom class to update the state?

I use `zustand` to manage user account login state, I create an `accountInfoStore` with `zustand` and `immer` middleware like below

```
export const useAccountStore = create(immerMiddleware(
    function (set) {
        let storeInfo = {
            accountData: new AccountData(),
            async updateAccountDataFromStorage() {
                set(function (state) {
                    state.accountData.fromStorage();
                });
            }
            async updatePassword(){
                let newpwd = await asyncRequestPassword();
                set(function (state) {
                    state.accountData.password = newpwd;
                })
            }
        }
    })
);
```

`accountData` is a custom class instance, the custom class code example is below

```
export class AccountData {
    // Support immer middleware
    [immerable] = true;

    constructor(account: string | null, password: string | null) {
        this.account = account;
        this.password = password;
    }

    async fromStorage(): Promise<AccountData> {
        let [account, password] = await asyncRequest();
        this.account = account;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

---

In example above, `updatePassword` method could work properly, the method itself is `async`, however it first wait for the async data acquired, then call the `set()` method synchronously, this pattern could solve some async update problem.

However in another method, `updateAccountDataFromStorage`, since the `fromStorage()` method is in the custom class instance `accountData` in the state, so I need to access `state`, so I need to call `state.accountData.fromStorage()`, however, as mentioned above, `set()` don't like async function, and this won't work, with err msg below:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked at Proxy.fromStorage
```

So my question is, when using `zustand` and `immer` middleware, how can I call an `async` function in the state which will have side effect to the state to update the state. In this example, I want to call `state.accountData.fromStorage()`, this method is `async`, and will update the value in `accountData`

> Notice: I have tried the sync version of this pattern, that is call a sync method in the state which cause side effect, and in this case, the zustand and immer works properly, and the state is successfully updated

---

**What I tried**

I tried to put the update method outside the state, and use `let curState = useAccountStore.getState()` to get the current state, then call `curState.accountData.fromStorage()`, however this will cause error too

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'account' of object '#<AccountData>
```

---

If I used the wrong way? Or should I just change my pattern to avoid depending an `async` method's side effect in the state to update the current store?

Comment: Running into the same problem, would love to know how to work around this.